# Do all artifacts in the Worklight iphone/native folder get propagated from Worklight into the xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

Working with a partner who is creating a cordova plugin.

1. If we add framework folders and artifacts to the Frameworks directory under iphone->native in eclipse will they get pulled into the corresponding xcode project?
2. There are some flags that need to be added to the ‘Linking’ properties under build settings.  Does this need to be done through the xCode IDE?

Thanks!
JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some actions must be done in Xcode.

For example, if you are creating a Cordova plug-in, then you need to:

1. Edit config.xml - this can be done in Eclipse
2. Place the .m and .h files in the Classes folder - you can put them there while in Eclipse, but they will not be referenced in the Xcode project

   - for this you must first build the Worklight project
   - and then open it in Xcode and add the files you've placed in the Classes folder to the project it self
   - You would normally need to go to Xcode to create the plug-in to begin with, but assuming you downloaded a plug-in...

The same applies to frameworks.